# How to get char** std::vector<char>& out?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this vector

```
std::vector<char> myvector;
```

I get the pointer to first element

```
char* pBegin = &myvector[0];
```

I need to pass to function char**, so I am doing this

```
some_function(pConvert, &pBegin,
```

Is it possible to avoid using pBegin ? just use myvector

Comment: `&(myverctor.data)`, but what for?

Comment: Depends on what `some_function` does.

Comment: @ForceBru you can't take the address of an rvalue.

Comment: @Quentin unless you are on MSVC

Comment: @Slava - assume standard C++, not a particular flawed implementation.

Comment: @Slava Anything goes with people on MSVC... Remember kids, don't do MSVC.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer, but I got this error:  error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand

Comment: @Sgfdgf at least we know that you are not on MSVC

Comment: You need to realize why `some_function` requires `char**` first

Comment: The short answer to the question is "no".   `myvector[0]` returns a reference, so `&myvector[0]` is not an lvalue, and it's address cannot be computed (e.g. `&(&myvector[0])` will be diagnosed as an error).   Similarly, members like `data()` return a pointer, which is also not an lvalue, so - again - its address cannot be computed (e.g. `&myvector.data()` will be diagnosed as an error).

Comment: Be careful with what `some_function` does with it's parameter. It is (probably) either expecting to be able to reallocate a single C string, or is expecting an array of C strings. The former is going to invoke undefined behaviour, and the latter probably expects some terminating value that you need to ensure is present in your vector. It may also require that the array be terminated, in which case you will have to pass it a pointer to a `char *[2]`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use char** , you can change the vector definition like this `std::vector<char*> myvector` and your implementation can look something like this:

```
bool some_function(char* other, const std::vector<char*>& vec)
{
    for (char* str : vec)
    {
        if (strcmp(str, other) == 0) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<char*> myvector;

    char  *ch1 = new char[6];
    strcpy(ch1, "Hello");

    myvector.push_back(ch1);

    char  *ch2 = "World";
    myvector.push_back(ch2);

    char** str1 = &myvector[0];
    char** str2 = &myvector[1];

    cout << (*str1) << endl;
    cout << (*str2) << endl;

    cout << (some_function("Hello",myvector) ? "Found" : " Not found") <<endl;
    delete ch1;
}
```